# Pass multiple args in Ember JS prop

Tags: ember.js

I have a function that lives in a component and I want to pass multiple arguments to it from the parent. I realise I can pass them individually but I'd like to pass them as one arg if possible.

I'd like this to work but the syntax in `actionArgs` isnt correct

```
<MyComponent @actionName={{myAction}} @actionArgs={{myValue, myOptions}} />

<button {{on "click" (action @actionName @actionArgs)}}></button>
```

I've tried wrapping in parenthesis but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 3):

Amazingly this can be done by passing in the fn arguments with the `fn` helper

```
<MyComponent @actionName={{fn myAction myValue myOptions}} />

<button {{on "click" (action @actionName)}}></button>
```

Comment: I'll tell you more - you don't have to use the `(action}` anymore, just make it `{{on "click" @actionName}}`

Comment: Sounds about right. I was wondering why weren't you using the fn from the very beginning. Good luck!

Comment: Hah yes youre right, didnt notice this was legacy code. Thanks I'll update it.